# Getting bizarre "expected primary-expression" error

Tags: c++, methods

I'm getting a really strange error when making a method call:

```
   /* input.cpp */

#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>
#include "input.h"
#include "command.h"

Input::Input ()
{
    raw ();
    noecho ();
}

Command Input::next ()
{
    char input = getch ();
    Command nextCommand;

    switch (input)
    {
    case 'h':
        nextCommand.setAction (ACTION_MOVELEFT);
        break;
    case 'j':
        nextCommand.setAction (ACTION_MOVEDOWN);
        break;
    case 'k':
        nextCommand.setAction (ACTION_MOVEUP);
        break;
    case 'l':
        nextCommand.setAction (ACTION_MOVERIGHT);
        break;
    case 'y':
        nextCommand.setAction (ACTION_MOVEUPLEFT);
        break;
    case 'u':
        nextCommand.setAction (ACTION_MOVEUPRIGHT);
        break;
    case 'n':
        nextCommand.setAction (ACTION_MOVEDOWNLEFT);
        break;
    case 'm':
        nextCommand.setAction (ACTION_MOVEDOWNRIGHT);
        break;
    case '.':
        nextCommand.setAction (ACTION_WAIT);
        break;
    }


    return nextCommand;
}
```

and the error:

```
Administrator@RHYS ~/code/rogue2
$ make
g++ -c -Wall -pedantic -g3 -O0 input.cpp
input.cpp: In member function `Command Input::next()':
input.cpp:21: error: expected primary-expression before '=' token
input.cpp:24: error: expected primary-expression before '=' token
input.cpp:27: error: expected primary-expression before '=' token
input.cpp:30: error: expected primary-expression before '=' token
input.cpp:33: error: expected primary-expression before '=' token
input.cpp:36: error: expected primary-expression before '=' token
input.cpp:39: error: expected primary-expression before '=' token
input.cpp:42: error: expected primary-expression before '=' token
input.cpp:45: error: expected primary-expression before '=' token
make: *** [input.o] Error 1
```

Sorry about the lack of linenumbers, the errors occur on the lines "nextCommand.setAction(...)", which is totally bizarre considering that they don't contain a '='.

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Rhys

Comment: Are the identifiers in all-caps macros, and if so, to what do they expand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the only thing I can think of (without seeing more code) that would cause this:

Your identifiers in all-caps are macros, defined something like this:

```
#define ACTION_MOVELEFT = 1
#define ACTION_MOVEDOWN = 2
```

and so on.  When the macros are then expanded, you end up with code like:

```
case 'h':
    nextCommand.setAction (= 1);
    break;
```

The `=` is not used to define a macro; for object-like macros, everything following the macro name until the newline ending the macro definition is part of the replacement list.  So, the macros should be defined as follows:

```
#define ACTION_MOVELEFT 1
#define ACTION_MOVEDOWN 2
```

and so on.

However, you should consider using an enumeration to enforce type safety and to avoid using the preprocessor when it doesn't need to be used:

```
enum ActionType
{
    ActionMoveLeft,
    ActionMoveDown
};
```

Or, at the very least, use `const int`s rather than `#define`s.

Comment: +1, that's probably it. Of course, it would be even smarter to use const int's instead of defines since they will carry type information as well (compiler objects rather than preprocessort objects).

Comment: @paxdiablo:  Agreed.  Or even better, an enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you're sure the errors are on the lines you think they're on, and the character being complained about doesn't exist, you should look to see what the preprocessor is expanding those lines into, such as by using the `gcc -E` flag to see the output of said preprocessor.

I suspect `ACTION_MOVELEFT` and its brethren may be expanding to something unexpected, but only viewing the preprocessor output will tell you for sure.